# What is the best uploadify Plugin with out flash and browser compatibility

Tags: asp.net

Currently I am using jQuery uploadify plugin which works fine in Chrome and IE but not in Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, have you looked at https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload, it has excellent [browser support](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Browser-support) and doesn't require Flash.

It's also [straightforward to implement](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin).

Otherwise, if you're able to leverage HTML5, this has excellent support for file uploading. MDN has [plenty of examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) and there's good demos [here](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/drag-and-drop-uploader/) and [here](http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload).

Comment: I am using jQuery uploadify.js  because i want to show progress bar also while uploading a file. For me Uplodify is not working in Firefox and Safari.

Comment: What error do you get in Firefox and Safari? What backend are you using - ASP.NET or something else?